# Recursive backtracking in Racket?

Tags: graph, racket, hamiltonian-cycle, recursive-backtracking

A while ago, as a proof of concept (and because I was using Logo with my autistic son) I wrote a program in Logo to find a Hamiltonian circuit in a graph (if it exists) using a backtracking method.  The basic backtracking schema I used was:

```
boolean hamilton(path p, graph g) 
  {
  if p has as many vertices as g 
    {
    if the last and first vertices in p are adjacent, 
      return true
    else 
      return false
    } 
  else 
    {
    for each vertex x of g not in p and adjacent to the last vertex of p
      {
      if hamilton(path p + x,graph g) succeeds, 
        return true
      }
    return false
    }
  }
```

and you can see a discussion [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit594-2012/Pages/backtracking.html).  I could do this easily in Logo because it allows multiple exit points from a function with the `OUTPUT` command.

However, Racket doesn't allow multiple exit points (at least, not easily).  So I'm hoping to be pointed in the direction of some material which would explain (a) how to manage multiple exit points from a function (I have a vague notion I can do it with continuations, as with `let/ec`) or (b) how to manage recursive backtracking in Racket in a way maybe better suited to the language.

As a newcomer to Racket, I'm sure this could be done in the twinkling of an eye by an expert, or even by anybody less of a raw beginner then me.  But right now I fund myself quite stumped.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
(define (hamilton p g)
  (if (>= (number-of-vertices p)
          (number-of-vertices g))
      (first-and-last-vertex-adjacent? p)
      (for/or ([v (in-vertices g)])
        (and (not (belongs-to-path v p))
             (not (adjacent v) (last-vertex p))
             (hamilton (append-vertex p x) g)))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm still learning about constructs such as `for/or` which I never would have thought of using - I would have tried for an ungainly (and no doubt incorrect) nesting of if statements.  I'll check this schema out.

Comment: It works fine!  Brilliant!  The only change (and maybe I wasn't clear in my initial description) was to remove the "not" from the second-last line: we do want the test vertex v to be adjacent to the last vertex of p.